# Scrollbar affects margin:0 auto; property and moves a page a few px to the right

Tags: html, css, position, positioning, center

This is an excerpt from my code:

```
<div id="column2">
  <div id="textbox">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <div id="text">
      <img id="portrait" src="images/portrait.png"/>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sollicitudin tristique posuere. Phasellus quis rhoncus felis. </p>
      <p>Curabitur condimentum gravida lorem, non accumsan justo facilisis non. Nam at nisi venenatis tortor viverra posuere.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code for that excerpt:

```
#textbox {
    background:lightgrey;
    margin:38px 0 0 0;
    width:400px;
    font-size:0.825em;
    line-height:150%;
}

#textbox p {
    margin-top:0;
}

#textbox h3 {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

#column2 {
    float:right;
    margin-right:150px;
}

#portrait {
    float:right;
    margin:0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

What is wrong is that when I don't have an image in "textbox" div, the center is different than the center with an image. I am using margin: 0 auto; to center whole wrapper div that is not included here. 
I would probably be able to center it properly with absolute positioning (didn't test it yet), but why the image affects the center? The whole wrapper div goes about 5-10px to the right, because of the image (I tested it). Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uVSTJ/1/

Edit: if i'm not using any center positioning, no problem occurs.

**Edit 2:** I found the problem, but don't know how to solve it. It only happens when I reach the bottom of a page, and a scrollbar appears. I suppose it starts calculating margins or something from a different place, what results in + several pixels to the right. Any way to solve this without using overflow property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 to 10px reminds me of a scrollbar. Maybe the image causes the heigth of the web page to exceed the height of the window in which case a scrollbar will be added. This causes the content to move a little bit.

Comment: thanks. yes, it is the problem I have, and don't know how to solve it. it has something to do with margins I guess, that are calculated different when having/not having scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

What are the styles for `#text`? And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be really helpful, because there **may** be some preceding `divs` with styles that might affect the layout.

Comment: it is empty. i was about to use it, but didn't

Comment: I have updated the initial post by uploading the whole column, but apparently it doesn't have a problem like I have. I also tried to upload whole site code, but it's the same, no problems. Don't know what is wrong with testing on my computer.

Comment: This is what I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/DriftingSteps/DcrZY/3/

The layout seems fine, even though I'm still wondering why the `margin-right: 150px;` is necessary on `#column2`. What do you exactly mean by 'center'? Even if I remove the image, the layout seems pretty fine as you can see here - http://jsfiddle.net/DriftingSteps/DcrZY/5/.
The only difference I see is the height of the green box (`#textbox`), which I believe is fine.

Comment: it's because I use 960px width (wrapper), and to make content closer to each other, I use margins to push them to the center. but thanks for your help, overflow:hidden; solved the problem :)

Comment: Good to know. I hope `overflow: hidden` won't hide parts of your content :D

Comment: hmm, actually I encounter problems with overflow again, just others. need to solve this without overflow property. going to update the main post soon